# Access Unique Constraint error in lib/pq

Tags: postgresql, go

I would like to handle a postgresql unique constraint error by accessing the error code. I have gone through these articles [here](https://www.goinggo.net/2014/10/error-handling-in-go-part-i.html) and [here](https://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go) and also gone through the documentation [here](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/lib/pq/-/blob/error.go#L446:18$references), but still don't quite understand how to implement this and access the errorcode returned by the db. It seems only the Message field method was implemented:

```
func (err Error) Error() string {
    return "pq: " + err.Message
}
```

If I want to access the SQLSTATE code, Do I implement something like:

```
func (err *Error) Error() string {
  return err.Code
}
```

and assume the Error struct as defined [here](https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#Error) will be available.

I have tried something in my handler like this:

```
sqlInsert := INSERT INTO usrtable (usrCode, teamName, email, phone) VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4)

_, err := db.Exec(sqlInsert, Data.UsrCode, Data.Teamname, Data.Email, Data.Phone)
if err != nil {
        switch err {
        case errorCodeNames["23505"]:
            // Return web page identifying field and advising user what to do.
            return
```

This returns undefined which makes sense since errorCodeNames is not exported but I am stumped regarding how to achieve this.

Comment: Do `e, ok := err.(*pq.Error)` if ok is true, then `e` is of type https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#Error and has access to the fields. Read more on [Go type assertion here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions).

Comment: https://github.com/lib/pq/issues/492#issuecomment-243231666

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this if you are using Postgres:

```
if pgErr, ok := err.(*pq.Error); ok {
    if pgErr.Code == "23505" {
        //handle duplicate insert
    }
}
```